# Jboss - handshake failure - client connection using TLSv1.1 instead of TLSv1.2

Tags: java, jboss, java-7

I have a jboss version Version 6.3.0.GA , using java version 1.7.0_71
My collegues on remote server changes allowed TLS protocol from 1.1 to 1.2, and now i have to update my client (deployed in jboss).
The problem is that after this change i receive:

```
faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

In ssl debug i see:

```
5:22:43,921 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) *** ClientHello, TLSv1
15:22:43,923 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) RandomCookie:  GMT: 1467638563 bytes = { 250, 245, 94, 108, 232, 16, 43, 124, 53, 95, 38, 104, 249, 96, 71, 207, 230, 7, 84, 183, 41, 224, 63, 213, 186, 7, 179, 255 }
15:22:43,923 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Session ID:  {}
15:22:43,923 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
15:22:43,924 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Compression Methods:  { 0 }
15:22:43,924 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
15:22:43,924 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
15:22:43,925 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: cxg7d.test.centurylink.com]
15:22:43,925 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ***
15:22:43,925 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 184
15:22:43,958 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
15:22:43,959 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
15:22:43,959 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, called closeSocket()
15:22:43,960 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
15:22:43,963 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) AxisFault
15:22:43,964 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
15:22:43,964 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  faultSubcode: 
15:22:43,964 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Even after below change has been applied

1 - updated the "standalone.xml" with below values

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="https.protocols" value="TLSv1.2"/>
</system-properties>
```

2 - added below JAVA Options to server start:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

3 - Changed graphically the protocols in java console
[JDK control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moJhq.png)

but nothing handshake still exists.
I suppose that the error is on "Client Hello" that still use TLSv1 instead of 1.2 .
Do youhave any suggestion to force this value?
S.

Answer (score 0):

No way to force TLSv1.2 for Java 1.7.0_71 using properties file.
The only way that worked is to add the following java code into program:

```
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv2Hello", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
```